ERROR: The postinstall intercept hook 'update_pixbuf_cache' failed
I'm making a Yocto Image with Poky (Dunfell) in a brand new installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 (No GUI, Physical laptop).
But even if I delete full the sstate folder and the build folder, i keep getting this error:
NOTE: Running ['oe-pkgdata-util', '-p', '/home/ubuntu/personal-yocto/build-prod/tmp/pkgdata/fs053', 'glob', '/tmp/installed-pkgsy30aimgu', '']

NOTE: Installing complementary packages ... (skipped already provided packages )

NOTE: Running intercept scripts:

NOTE: > Executing update_pixbuf_cache intercept ...

NOTE: Exit code 2. Output:

/home/ubuntu/personal-yocto/build-prod/tmp/work/fs053-poky-linux-gnueabi/timesys-initramfs/1.0-r0/intercept_scripts-936c734ca91129d39e287aacdf9bd9ccb02b9f5f0b9cce5a8c66db581ec62aa4/update_pixbuf_cache: 11: cannot create /home/ubuntu/personal-yocto/build-prod/tmp/work/fs053-poky-linux-gnueabi/timesys-initramfs/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/../loaders.cache: Directory nonexistent

This are the stepts that i followed of the Dunfell packages
    # Update the package repositories
    sudo apt-get update

    # Install essential packages
    sudo apt-get install -y gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib build- essential chrpath socat cpio python3 python3-pip python3-pexpect xz-utils debianutils iputils-ping python3-git python3-jinja2 libegl1-mesa libsdl1.2-dev pylint3 xterm python3-subunit mesa-common-dev

    # Set locales
    sudo apt-get install locales
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
    sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
    sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Then I just wen to the folder and tried to build the image using the imx guide:
    cd ~/personal-yocto
    PS1='$PWD\$'
    . imx-build-env test
    bitbake -c cleanall imx-image-test
    bitbake imx-image-test

Just to consider, the personal Yocto, I just copied the full folder that has the recipes sources, repo and also the downloads from a Yocto Server (Centos) that's properly working and building the image without issues.
This is the full log of the error
Is there any package that I'm missing?
Can be a path issue with this line?

loaders.cache: Directory nonexistent

Thanks in advance for your help, I tried with another packages, or configurations but nothing has worked.
UPDATE 2024-07-24
I was able to figure it out, since it was a backup of the complete recipe in another server, including downloads files, there was some folders on "download" that has the path, so I need to update those paths and it worked.
I need to do this since the new server has no internet connection, so will close the question.

Try deleting everything under build/tmp folder and try again.

UPDATE 2024-07-24
I was able to figure it out, since it was a backup of the complete recipe in another server, including downloads files, there was some folders on "download" that has the path, so I need to update those paths and it worked.
I need to do this since the new server has no internet connection, so will close the question.
